# code for retry option in snack bar

Tags: android

I have a splash activity where I check if there is any internet connection or not. If not then it will show a `Snackbar` message. In `Snackbar` I put a retry option when the user clicks on it. It will again check for an internet connection and goto the next Activity.

```
if(!isConnectedToInternet()){
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             //What do I write here?

            }
        });



}

private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Comment: You should use alert dialog instead of snack bar..

Comment: Please try something before asking for help. StackOverflow is not here for someone else to write the code for you.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution to your problem would be this.
You had forgotten to call the Snackbar show method, set the Snackbar click

```
    if(!isConnectedToInternet()){
          Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
             .make(view, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
             .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                      isConnectedToInternet();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NextActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);                           
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
             });
       snackbar.show(); 
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
       ConnectivityManager cm =
                        (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the exact same thing in this way:

First put your main code in a method like mainMethod() and call it from onCreate().

In onCreate(), call the method like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(!isConnectedToInternet(MainActivity.this)){
        showSnackBar("No Internet Connection", (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llmainActivity));
    }

    else {
        mainMethod();
    }
}
```

The methods are like this

```
public void mainMethod(){
  //your main method
 }

public void showSnackBar(String string, LinearLayout linearLayout)
{
    Snackbar.make(linearLayout, string, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).
            setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!isConnectedToInternet(MainActivity.this)){
                        showSnackBar("No Internet Connection",(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llmainActivity));
                    }
                    else mainMethod();
                }
            }).show();
}

private boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```